# How can I add these if and elif statements into a single string instead of printing out each statement on its own line?

Tags: python, string, for-loop, if-statement, append

```
def main():
    phoneNumber = str(input('Please enter your phone number (XXX-XXX-XXXX): '))

    for count in phoneNumber:
        if count == '0':
            print('0')
        elif count == '1':
            print('1')
        elif count == 'A' or count == 'B' or count == 'C' or count == '2':
            print('2')
        elif count == 'D' or count == 'E' or count == 'F' or count == '3':
            print('3')
        elif count == 'G' or count == 'H' or count == 'I' or count == '4':
            print('4')
        elif count == 'J' or count == 'K' or count == 'L' or count == '5':
            print('5')
        elif count == 'M' or count == 'N' or count == 'O' or count == '6':
            print('6')
        elif count == 'P' or count == 'Q' or count == 'R' or count == 'S' or count == '7':
            print('7')
        elif count == 'T' or count == 'U' or count == 'V' or count == '8':
            print('8')
        elif count == 'W' or count == 'X' or count == 'Y' or count == 'Z' or count == '9':
            print('9')
        elif count == '-':
            print('-')
        else:
            print('Please enter uppercase alphanumeric symbols, and dashes("-")')

main()
```

I tried using the return function and that would not output anything, I tried using a running total for count and it just displayed the number twice in a string instead of the whole number. I cannot figure out how to make this work, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could also simplify the code by using `if count in 'ABC2':`  etc instead of the multiple `or` conditions.

Comment: Instead of printing inside the loop, append the character to a string. Then print the whole string at the end.

Comment: You could also use a dictionary to map letters to numbers, instead of lots of `if` statements.

Comment: rather than all those print() calls, you might initialize an empty list and then append into it then print the populated list after the loop maybe using join()